# Django sorl-thumbnail don't store files in my app

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I read several topics here about this problem, but I can't manage to resolve it. Everybody asks if the `MEDIA_ROOT` config is okay, and other answer "yes sure!" But I did not find a real explanation, so:

I can see the generated filename (from db) in my template (a pdf genreated by weasyprint) :

```
/media/ cache/92/00/9200d02288657e7accae5666d37188a1.jpg
```

The `object.exists` in the thumbnail template tags returns, without surprise, `False`.

The file isn't generated.
In my settings.py I have this config :

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

That worked fine with a basically `FileUpload` field.

I think I just don't understand the path configuration of MEDIA stuff.

Some explanations on good practices about dealing with `MEDIA` will be welcome !

**EDIT :** I uninstalled sorl-thumbnail and now use easy-thumbnails.

Comment: If you want some kind of "meaningful" path to each thumbnail, then you probably don't need `sorl-thumbnail` at all ... Are you trying to store generated thumbnail in `ImageField`?

Comment: Hi, I just need to generate thumbnails when a template is called and if they don't already exist and to store them. I actually use the ImageField from the sorl-thumbnail package.